# General way to monitor ALL memory usages

Tags: memory-usage, zfs, free

I have Kubuntu 16.04 and am using ZFS.

As you can see on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1130972/nothing-seems-to-account-for-5gb-of-memory-that-is-missing-under-linux), I just had a long journey in tracking down where my memory was vanishing to.

It turned out to be the ARC of ZFS that was eating it up without showing up anywhere in the tools/files other than its own special file `/proc/spl/kstat/zfs/arcstats`

**Is there a generic way to see how much memory is used by the kernel and if possible, by which kernel modules?**

**Example:**

free -h was showing me this:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available                                           
Mem:            31G         19G        1.8G        406M         10G        5.2G                                           
Swap:          8.0G          0B        8.0G
```

So 19GB in use. But TOP only showed me about 8GB of used memory. So I went in search of the other 11GB. 
6GB turned out to be slab which can be seen in `/proc/memstat` and with `nmon`. But 5GB were still missing.

In the end I found that it had been consumed by the ARC of ZFS. But it was only listed in its own special info file. `/proc/spl/kstat/zfs/arcstats`

Neither `/proc/memstat` nor `top`, `htop`, `nmon`, `free`, or `atop` could tell me who is using those 5GB.

Is there a file/tool to see the memory used by such **special** modules, without knowing/understanding those modules? Or do I have to account for every existing module if I would want to write a monitoring tool that can tell me this?

From my perspective, memory info under linux is a total mess. Dozen of number that all don't add up to total memory. I bet `free` calculates the "in use" parameter by substracting free/cache/buffers from the total.

**I would like to have/write a tool/info where I can see**

```
Total memory: 32GB
  in use: 19GB
    processes: 8GB
    slab: 5GB
    mapper: 1Gb
    kernel modules: 5Gb
       kernel: 0.3GB
       spl: 4.7GB
  cache: 6GB
  buffers: 2GB
  free: 5GB
Additional stats:
  Active memory: 8.3GB
    Active(anon): 7.1GB
    Active(file): 1.2GB
  Inactive memory: 2.4GB
  ...
```

You know, where each subsection actually addes up to its parent section and each byte of memory is accounted for ;)

**So is such a tool possible under Linux? Does it exist already?**

**Update 1**

The tool smem as suggested below indeed shows a colum "Dynamic kernel memory" which sums up to 100% of memory and accounts for ARC.
**However** according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62066/what-is-kernel-dynamic-memory-as-reported-by-smem)

> BTW: I already checked smem sources, it basically does (memtotal - userspace - free - cache).

So this is only achieved by simply substracting all known figures from /proc/memstat and labeling what is **missing** as "noncache Dynamic Kernel Memory" I find this disturbing and really hope the linux kernel has more to offer than that.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34795/correctly-determining-memory-usage-in-linux/169129#169129

Comment: @ElderGeek: you should copy that here and refer to that one as your source...  :D

Comment: @Fabby Done....

Comment: Conky displays the top 9 processes using RAM and I'm sure 5GB would stand out as one of the top 9 as it's hard to imagine 9 other processes using more than 5 GB.

Answer (score 9):

You might try `smem` for at least a goodly portion of what you are looking for.

It's available in the Universe repository and can be installed with `sudo apt-get install smem`

There are a number of useful switches that are covered on the man page `man smem`

Some examples are as follows:
Note I'm using the -t switch for totals in all examples for brevity. you can leave it out if you want more verbose output.

```
PSS is the interesting column in these examples as it takes shared memory into account.
Unlike RSS it's meaningful to add it up.
```

**System Wide**

```
me@zippy-64bit:~$ smem -tw
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0 
kernel image                      0          0          0 
kernel dynamic memory        989656     860076     129580 
userspace memory             936032     180020     756012 
free memory                 5692716    5692716          0 
----------------------------------------------------------
                            7618404    6732812     885592
```

**By user**

```
me@zippy-64bit:~$ smem -tu
User     Count     Swap      USS      PSS      RSS 
me          67        0   861452   898915  1245592 
---------------------------------------------------
            67        0   861452   898915  1245592
```

Also of note are [smemcap](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=smemcap&searchon=names) for capture of data for future analysis with `smem` and [smemstat](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/smemstat/) which reports the physical memory usage taking into consideration shared memory. The tool can either report a current snapshot of memory usage or periodically dump out any changes in memory.

There's also a list at the bottom of the page of [similar packages.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/smem)

Sources:

- [Correctly determining memory usage in Linux - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34795/correctly-determining-memory-usage-in-linux/169129#169129)
- [`man smem`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/smem.8.html)
- [Ubuntu – Details of package smem in xenial](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/smem)
- [Smemstat - shared memory statistics](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/smemstat/)

**Alternative 1:** You might also consider parsing the output of `cat /proc/meminfo` or if you want it by the page `less /proc/meminfo`

Much of the information here is used by `free`, `top` and `ps` commands. In fact, the output of the free command is similar in appearance to the contents and structure of /proc/meminfo. But by looking directly at /proc/meminfo, many more details are revealed including :

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep "Slab"
Slab:             267680 kB
```

Alternative Source: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-proc-topfiles.html

**Alternative 2:** If you are truly committed to a better parsing of kernel RAM you might [roll your own kstat.](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/tree/09f79f7c66b85f056db11f58210dc6182c9b1aef/usr/src/cmd/stat/kstat) While `kstat` appears to be a Solaris only command. the link above will take you to sources for for an open source attempt at `kstat` that was last modified in 2013 (as of this edit.) A clever C programmer might be able to modify the code for their specific purpose.

Alternative 2 [source:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214666/kstat-in-solaris-11)

Comment: and upgoated!  ;-)

Comment: Hi, thanks! One upvote for the start. I'll check into it in more details in the evening. But I am a bit disapointet. While smem certainly does show the ARC as part of "kernel dynamic memory" this is just another puzzlepiece (no slab info for example) and this tool installs a lot of unwanted packages with it. (Guess for pie charts??) So I would like to understand where it gets this "kernel dynamic memory" number from, maybe I can get it also without smem? But at least smem attributes each byte of memory to some actor.

Comment: @Torge expanded answer. I believe all of this data comes from `/proc/meminfo`

Comment: @ElderGeek Unfortunately not. /proc/meminfo and /proc/slabinfo were my first tries to track down my memory consumption. If it were there I would not have asked in the first place :( See my original question linked in the first line of this question for details on that.

Comment: Just found [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62066/what-is-kernel-dynamic-memory-as-reported-by-smem) and there it says:
"BTW: I already checked smem sources, it basically does (memtotal - userspace - free - cache)."

This is NOT how I think a kernel should report it's memory usage. This is ridiculous. (A is used by X, B is used by Y, C is free and the rest? Dunno used by something... lets call it Dynamic Kernel Memory)

Comment: @Torge Oh, are you using zram? That will clearly throw the totals off currently. (this too may pass) I'm sorry my answer doesn't take into consideration your new edit. I look forward to seeing better answers

Comment: No, I do not use zram. Don't even know what this is *G*. Just stumbled uppon this answer when searching for dynamic kernel memory and it turned out to be just the label smem gives memory it can't see.
I'll give you the bounty, if there does not show up any better answer until the period ends. Still hope someone saves the honor of the linux kernel ;)

Comment: @Torge The only thing I've been able to find that might delve as deeply into kernel RAM as you would like is `kstat` but this appears to be Solaris dependent. Answer updated.